# SQL - How to make a BEFORE UPDATE trigger work as a BEFORE INSERT?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, sql-function

Someone just helped me create a trigger with the following structure:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `newTeacher` BEFORE INSERT ON `members`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE
BEGIN
    Declare fieldInfo varchar(30);

    SELECT field_2 INTO fieldInfo 
      FROM pfields_cont 
     WHERE pfields_cont.member_id = NEW.member_ID;

    IF fieldInfo = 'Teacher' THEN
        SET NEW.member_group_id = 6;
    END IF;
END;
```

What I'm trying to do is basically change the user's group if 'Teacher' is found in one of the registration fields.

**The code works fine with BEFORE UPDATE, but not with BEFORE INSERT.** It doesn't throw any errors. It just doesn't do anything.

**I was told it's because member_id is autoincremented, and its number isn't known when the trigger fires.**

Could anybody point me the solution? **Or transform that into a procedure or function, instead of a trigger?**

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `member_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `member_group_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `email` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
  KEY `bday_day` (`bday_day`),
  KEY `ip_address` (`ip_address`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `member_groups` (`member_group_id`,`mgroup_others`(188))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=161 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in an insert trigger.

In a BEFORE insert trigger, the auto-increment value hasn't been generated yet.

In an AFTER insert trigger, you can't `SET NEW.member_group_id`.

You can do an UPDATE after your INSERT is done. I.e. not in a trigger, but from the client.

Or you can specify a primary key value instead of relying on the auto-increment. This means you need some other way of generating unique id values.

Comment: Maybe creating a procedure or a function would solve it? The thing is, I'm clueless about it.

Comment: Only if that procedure does what I described: INSERT then UPDATE the row you just inserted. But I would just do that in client code.

Comment: Would that be too difficult? Would you help to create the procedure, please?

Comment: No, I'm not going to give you a tutorial on stored procedures. There are books and documentation and plenty of examples about that topic.

Comment: Anything you can link me that would give me a better direction for my case?

Comment: I'm telling you honestly: don't bother with stored procedures. They are not a good solution. I don't use them.